# Two cards are randomly drawn without replacement from a common 52 card deck, P(Jack)=?

Tags: probability, independence

Q: Two cards are randomly drawn without replacement from a 52 card deck of 
   common playing cards. What is the probability of drawing a Jack?
I have found a few ways to answer this problem, one the ways I prefer but don't fully understand. Here is my solution:

$$P(J_1 \cup J_2)=P(J_1)+P(J_2)-P(J_1\cap J_2)=1/13+1/13-(1/13)\cdot (3/51)=33/221$$

$33/221$ is the correct final answer but I'm not sure how these inputs can be correct, for instance how is P(J<sub>1</sub>)=
P(J<sub>2</sub>)?

Comment: The reason that the result is correct is that you can start with a card not being a jack. In this case, you have a larger probability to draw a jack in the second try , in total $P(J_2)$ has the same probability as you can calculate considering the two possible cases.

Comment: But why not calculate the probability to draw no jack and subtract it from $1$ ?

Comment: Is your question why $P(J_1) = P(J_2) = 1/13$ and $P(J_1 \cap J_2) = \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{3}{51}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an intuitive way:

$P(Jack)=1-P(Jack^\complement)=1$-${48}\choose{2}$/${52}\choose{2}$

I use combinations to calculate $P(Jack^\complement)$:

- There are ${52}\choose{2}$ ways to draw two cards without replacement
- There are ${48}\choose{2}$ ways to do the same thing without Jacks

Comment: Why is it a combination? Doesn't that factor out some of the ways to draw the cards? For ex . (3 Hearts, 5 Spades) = (5 Spades, 3 hearts) count as one way with combinations, but aren't they two distinct ways to draw two cards without replacement?. The ratio is the same if I use permutations which seems to make more sense.

Comment: It depends from the sample space you fix. I find more natural choose the space of cominations of 2 cards extract from a deck of 52 cards. The important thing is take the right event. You can also work with the space of disposition without repetitions of 2 elements extract from a set of 52 and take a event which is a subset of that space. 

As you write, the ratio is the same so the answer obv doesn't change. I like to think drawing two cards as a choise.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t matter whether you draw the jacks simultaneously or one at a time. The probability that the first card is a jack is the same as that of the second card being a jack. You can verify this by computing these probabilities in two different ways.

First, drawing sequentially, the probability that the first draw is a jack is clearly $\frac1{13}$. For the second card, we have two cases: if you’ve already drawn a jack, the probability that the next card drawn is a jack is $\frac3{51}$. On the other hand, if you haven’t already drawn a jack, then it’s $\frac4{51}$. Putting these together using the Law of Total Probability, $$\Pr(\text{second card is a jack})=\frac1{13}\cdot\frac3{51}+\frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac4{51}=\frac1{13}.$$

If you’re drawing the cards simultaneously, then there are really two steps to the process: first you draw the two cards and then you place them into slots #1 and #2. There are four possible outcomes: no jacks in either slot, a jack in both slots, a jack in slot #1 only, or a jack in slot #2 only. We’re only interested in the last three, the probabilities of which are $$\begin{align}\Pr(\text{jack in slot #1 and jack in slot #2}) &= \frac4{52}\cdot\frac3{51} \\ \Pr(\text{jack in slot #1 only}) &= \frac4{52}\cdot\frac{48}{51} \\  \Pr(\text{jack in slot #2 only}) &=\frac{48}{52}\cdot\frac4{51}.\end{align}$$ The last two probabilities are obviously equal. These events are disjoint, so the overall probability of having a jack in slot #1 is the sum of the first and second values, as is the overall probability of having a jack in slot #2 (and is again equal to $\frac1{13}$).